# Good news for me, bad news for you

Tags: single-word-requests

I will be telling my employers that I am moving which could complicate life for them but it is a great step for me; a leap in fact.

I am searching for a word that will help me deliver some news that is good for me but bad, or not so good, for the party receiving the news.

Comment: Don't go there.  Thank them warmly for the opportunities, experience, coffee quality, encounters. décor, pot-plants. Softening the blow is rubbing salt in wounds, gloating, and Schadenfreude.

Comment: Might be better posted [over here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Hugh I wish they'd had pot plants where I worked.

Comment: selfish or incompassionate may be apt. Focus on the other, not yourself. If the good news is discussed by the other, you should discuss it humbly.

Comment: Something like: A **significant** event/episode/opportunity has **cropped up**, OR "I have received **a once in a lifetime opportunity**",  which I cannot afford to ignore/miss/lose out on. [*Such and such* etc...] I know this might put you in an awkward position/create a few headaches for you, so I'm willing to stay a week or two longer until you can find a replacement. (not a single word, I'm afraid)

Comment: Don't worry about it. You may feel attached, loyal, even sentimental; they don't.  You'd find that out if you were to stay long enough to get "RIF'd", "downsized", or otherwise disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

Bittersweet?

> both pleasant and painful or regretful

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bittersweet

E.g. a bittersweet goodbye

Answer (score 0):

Tell them that you are pursuing a once in a lifetime opportunity; that you cannot afford to pass this up.  You may feel sorry for the effects onto others of taking advantage of a good-for-you situation, but it has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

If they were wonderful employers who treated you really well, be polite and professional.  Say something like "I am truly sorry; it was a pleasure to work for you, but I cannot pass up this opportunity."  They'll be happy for the kind words, but probably place some importance on your happiness, and will understand.

If they were crappy employers who treated you horribly, be polite and professional.  Say something like "I am truly sorry; it was a pleasure to work for you, but I cannot pass up this opportunity."  Chances are they know they treat their workers like crap, and that your professionalism is you being better than them - and they'll boil in impotent anger.